# Facing error in local environment setup for arrow with c++

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

Facing undefined reference error while reading an apache arrow file in c++ using apache arrow libraries. Basically I'm trying to read an arrow file generated by java in the apache arrow format.
I'm using apache arrow in c++ to read the file.

Below is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <arrow/io/api.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/api.h>
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/csv/api.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/reader.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/writer.h>
#include <arrow/status.h>

using namespace arrow;

arrow::Status GenInitialFile()
{

  std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> file;
  const std::string file_path = "userdata_to_arrow.arrow";
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(file, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(file_path, arrow::default_memory_pool()));

  std::shared_ptr<arrow::ipc::RecordBatchFileReader> reader;
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto ipc_reader, arrow::ipc::RecordBatchFileReader::Open(file));

  std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> record_batch;
  arrow::Status status;
  while (true)
  {
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> rbatch;
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(rbatch, ipc_reader->ReadRecordBatch(0));
    std::cout << "Read record batch with " << record_batch->num_rows() << " rows." << std::endl;
  }

  return arrow::Status::OK();
}

int main()
{
  
  arrow::Status st = GenInitialFile();

  if (!st.ok())
  {
    std::cerr << st << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Facing error like

```
read_arrow.cpp:22: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5arrow19default_memory_poolEv'
```

My `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x86-windows/include",
                "${default}",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\arrow",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\arrow-flight-glib",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\arrow-flight-sql-glib",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\arrow-flight-glib",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\arrow-glib",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\arrow-dataset-glib",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\grpc",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\grpc++"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I'm using VS code for building and development in c++ with microsoft c++ extension.
Trying to understand if I'm missing any library linking ?